# Prove strictly positive-definite kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

It can be shown that the Hamming distance defines a positive semi-definite kernel (see e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270181/how-to-prove-a-hamming-distance-as-a-kernel)). However, is the kernel
$$ K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}\{x_i = y_i\}$$
*strictly* positive-definite? That is, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $c_1,\dots, c_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots, \mathbf{x}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) > 0. $$

Moreover, is the kernel defined by $\exp\{K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})\}$ *strictly* positive-definite?

Comment: $K(x,x) = 0$ ...

Comment: @user251257 What about the second question?

Comment: In the definition of strictly positive definite one usually requires that $x_i \neq x_j$ for $i \neq j$.